# Make UIView fix position to the top of UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar

I want to make custom Navigation Bar using UIView but I don't want to embed Navigation Controller. I have tried making UIView but end up the UIView is scrollable. The main thing about Navigation Bar is sticked to the top whether the UITableViewController scrolled or not.
How to make the custom Navigation Bar with UIView has fixed position like the original navigation bar. Thanks!

Comment: Use UIViewController rather then UITableViewController and add the view on top of UITableView and your view will never scroll :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a UITableViewController, you should probably use a regular UIViewController and then add a UITableView and your custom UIView as subviews. UITableViewControllers aren't very flexible when it comes to adding subviews. They are meant to take up the entire screen.

For static table views you need to add a UITableViewController as a Container ViewController to another UIViewController. So you will have one main UIViewController that has your custom UIView nav bar and a Container View Controller that holds your UITableViewController.

Comment: cannot using view controller because I want to make static table view

Comment: This is correct way.. I always go with the same. and its works perfect with tableview or other too.

Comment: I have tried this, but the xcode says Static Table Views are only valid when embedded with UITableViewController Instances. I use static table views only for styling since textfield label will be put inside it.

Comment: @chronycles so in that case you can create a UITableViewController and add it as a child view controller to another UIViewController. That UIViewController will then hold your UITableViewController child view controller and your custom UIView nav bar. Does that make sense?

Comment: I really don't know how to make this possible, mr. watkins. perhaps you could show me an example.

Comment: @chonycles in your storyboard, add a new UIViewController. Then search for "Container View" in the bottom right panel. Once you find it, drag that container view onto the UIViewController that you just added. When you add that container view, storyboard will add another view controller to the screen. That new view controller needs to become your UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

**Simply Create Table Header View.**
1.Using Table View Delegate Methods Create Header View Programatically of the Starting Cell.